# teratermでのショートカットでプロキシサーバの設定を入れる方法。

Tags: teraterm

会社の検証環境へteratermでログインをするにあたり、ショートカットを作成して自動的に（楽に）ログインをしたいです。
ただ、会社の検証環境ではプロキシ―サーバを使用しており、プロキシーサーバの設定を入れるショートカットの方法を教えてください。

Answer (score 1):

試してませんがオプションでproxyの指定ができるようです。

```
ttermpro.exe -proxy http://proxysv:port hostname /ssh
```

こんな感じでしょうか。

https://ttssh2.osdn.jp/manual/4/ja/commandline/ttproxy.html

Answer (score 0):

- ショートカットキーではありませんが、キー操作でプロキシの設定ダイアログが開きます。
  <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>s</kbd> <kbd>p</kbd>
- スクリプトでプロキシを切り替えたいのであれば、プロキシを設定した複数のiniファイルを用意しておき、スクリプトで必要なiniファイルを読み込んではいかがでしょう。※この方法は未検証です。

---

### 実績のある方法を紹介します(PW認証です)。

#### 自動ログイン(プロキシなし)

ショートカット(Win)

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\teraterm\ttermpro.exe" -proxy=none://  /M=ssh2loginWSL.ttl /F=TERATERM.INI
```

※　ttermpro.exeのオプションの方が効いているようです。

ssh2loginWSL.ttl

```
username = 'XXX'
hostname = 'XXXXX'
; delpassword 'password.dat' 'mypasswordWSL'
getpassword 'password.dat' 'mypasswordWSL' Password

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
msg = hostname
strconcat msg ':22 /ssh /auth=password /user='
strconcat msg username
strconcat msg ' /passwd='
strconcat msg Password
connect msg
```

※　usernameとhostnameは伏字

#### 自動ログイン(プロキシあり)

ショートカット(Win)

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\teraterm\ttermpro.exe" /M=ssh2login.ttl /F=XXTERATERM.INI
```

XXTERATERM.INI  ※プロキシはINIファイルで設定、コマンドのオプションで指定してもよい

```
[TTProxy]
ConnectionTimeout="10"
;httpしか使ったことがない
ProxyType="http"
;プロキシのIP
ProxyHost="999.999.999.999"
;プロキシのポート番号
ProxyPort="9999"
;ProxyUser= 使ったことがない
;ProxyPass= 使ったことがない
```

ssh2login.ttl

```
username = 'XXXX'
hostname = 'XXXXXXX'
getpassword 'password.dat' 'mypassword' Password

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

msg = hostname
strconcat msg ':22 /ssh /auth=password /user='
strconcat msg username
strconcat msg ' /passwd='
strconcat msg Password

connect msg
```

※　usernameとhostnameは伏字
※　プロキシなしのTTLと内容は実質的に同じです。